# Are Data Annotations working with interfaces?

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I would like to use POCO to define my business model (with EF code first). To force my developers and do generic checking I use interfaces:

```
public interface IId
{
    Guid Id { get; set;  }
}

public interface ICode
{
    string Code { get; set; }
    string CodeTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

So in my POCO I implement these interfaces

```
public class Item: IId, ICode
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string CodeTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

The implementation is correct and now I would like to automatically force the [Key] on my id and the [Required] on my code.

Can I do this?

```
public interface IId
{
    [Key]
    Guid Id { get; set;  }
}

public interface ICode
{
    [Required]
    string Code { get; set; }
    string CodeTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is stopping you from compile this code and look what will happen?

Comment: The code compile. For what I tested it doesn't work. See my question as "is it possible to make it working"?

Comment: When I add the attribute on the interface only the migration tool do not detect any change. This doesn't mean another system is not able to deal with interface.

Comment: I found a workaround with Fluent API for EF code first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40797800/196526